# Запрос в функции то вытаскивает, то не вытаскивает записи

Tags: sql-server, запрос

Здравствуйте!  
Вот такой вопрос `MS SQL SERVER 2008`, как-то странно работать стала функция: то вытаскивает записи, то нет (однозначно записи есть для запроса, написанного в функции).  
Может, кто знает, в чём тут проблема? (Раньше работало хорошо, недавно так стало.)

Comment: Какой уровень изоляции?

Comment: По умолчанию - read commited.

Comment: А что за недавнее время поменялось (Раньше работало хорошо, недавно так стало.)?

Comment: Добавилось условие, которое проверяется константным значением из таблицы.